# RXJS Stream - How to wait for my STREAM to end and return DATA and then do my OPERATIONS

Tags: javascript, websocket, async-await, rxjs

I have a Websocket Endpoint I am subscribing. I want to get that Data, and then operate on them.

**CODE:**

```
// Simple HTTP POST Request. Works Perfectly. I am Logged In to the API
const authenticationRequest = () => axios.post(authenticationUrl, {
  user: username, password
})
  .then((response) => response.data)
  .catch((error) => console.error(console.error('Error Response', error)));

// WS Request. I need to wait for this to return my Data and then operate on them
const wsRequest = async () => {
  // Getting the Auth Token. Working Perfectly.
  const reqToken = await authenticationRequest();

  // Hitting the ws Endplint. Working Perfectly.
  const webSocketRequest = new WebSocket(topicDataUrl);

  // Setting the Data for the First Message. Works Perfectly.
  const firstMessage = {
    token: reqToken,
    stats: 2,
    sql: "SELECT * FROM cc_payments LIMIT 100",
    live: false
  };

  // Initialising an Empty Array. Works.
  let websocketData = [];

  // Opening the Endpoint
  webSocketRequest.onopen = () => {

    // Sending the first Message
    webSocketRequest.send(JSON.stringify(firstMessage));

    // On Each Message
    webSocketRequest.onmessage = (streamEvent) => {
      of(streamEvent).pipe(
        map(event => JSON.parse(event.data)), // Parse the Data
        filter(message => message.type === 'RECORD') // Filter the Data
      ).subscribe(
        message => websocketData.push(message.data.value)// Adding each Value from each message to the Array.
      );
    };
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(websocketData), 'Websocket DATA'); // Empty Array
  return websocketData;
};
```

Here I am calling it a few lines down, but still with no results. I get an empty Array.

```
(async function () {
  const data = await wsRequest();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data), 'Data');  // Still Empty
}());
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Can someone, explain to me the problem? I mean I get the asynchronisity of things, but I am awaiting. I even tried setting a timeout but didn't work.

**Is my stream correct? Maybe there is a problem there??**

So, the RXJS Actions are asynchronous. So, I would need 2 Things.
- Close the Stream when Operationg Completed. (Tried `takeUntil`, `takeWhile`, but obviously was doing something wrong)
- Wait in order to return the Actual Data(`WebsocketData`).

**UPDATE:**

```
async function authenticationRequest() {
  const AuthenticateWith = await axios.post(authenticationUrl, {
    user: username,
    password
  })
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error:', error));

  return AuthenticateWith;
}
const webSocketRequest = new WebSocket(topicDataUrl);
const websocketData = new Array;
const subject = new Subject();

async function requestToWSEndpoint() {
  const reqToken = await authenticationRequest();

  const firstMessage = {
    token: reqToken,
    stats: 2,
    sql: "SELECT * FROM cc_payments LIMIT 100",
    live: false
  };

  webSocketRequest.onopen = () => {
    webSocketRequest.send(JSON.stringify(firstMessage));

    webSocketRequest.onmessage = (streamEvent) => {
      JSON.parse(streamEvent.data).type === 'RECORD' && websocketData.push(JSON.parse(streamEvent.data).data.value);
      subject.next(websocketData);
      JSON.parse(streamEvent.data).type === 'END' && subject.complete();
    };
  };
};

(async function () {
  requestToWSEndpoint();

  const chartData = subject.subscribe((event) => console.log(event, 'Event')); // Event Adds to the Array and at the End I have all my Items(Filtered). It printed 100 Times.
  console.log('ARRAY', chartData); // This returns [Subscriber {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}]. This is what I want. The Array.
}());
```

Comment: I am pretty new to RxJS. So, I would like to understand what is going on, with my code, I could certainly have written something wrong, but I would like to understand what that is. Thank you!

Comment: Although you await wsRequest, the subscription inside wsRequest isnt waited for. What happens is the following: you create the empty array, you set the onmessage handler, then the empty array is returned and after this the data is pushed inside websocketData. You are mixing two concepts here: streams and promises and the way you do it, it wont work. I'd recommend to use a subject inside the subscribe in the onmessage handler and then listen to subject changes inside the function inside your second code block.

Comment: Why do you want to use RxJS? It's better not to mix RxJS and Promises within one task if you can avoid it. You're already using Axios for http requests and JS WebSockets so stick with Promises. If you want to use RxJS use [rxjs/ajax](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/ajax/ajax) for http requests and [rxjs/websocket](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket) for websockets. You're currently only using RxJS for synchronous actions so I see no point in using it the way you want to.

Comment: You set `chartData` equal to the return of `subscribe` which, well, returns a `subscription`. With that `console.log('ARRAY', chartData);`you will never be able to log the array -  its just not how asynchronicity works in javascript. I will edit my answer to give a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion as outlined in my comment:

```
const subject = new Subject();
...
}
(async function () {
   wsRequest();
   subject.pipe(finalize(()=> {console.log('ARRAY', websocketData);})).subscribe();
 }());
```

Actually you dont even need a function for what you do in wsRequest, except for `const reqToken = await authenticationRequest();`. The rest can easily be globally scoped.

You should take a look at the documentation for `rxjs` `operators.`

Comment: I am confused. I followed your advice. And now on Every event, I get my Array Build. But the const `charData`, that I am assigning the `subject.subscribe()`, is returning this: `Subscriber {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, …}` instead of my Array?? Any Ideas? I am like 1 meters from the finish line.. I am reading the Docs, but I am kind of confused..

Comment: What do you pass in the `next` method? I mistakenly wrote `stream`, but it should be `websocketData` i.e. the array.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I updated the answer with the code, I wrote. I get the Array and the new Item on each event. But I want to Array of Items, when the stream completes. That why I added the `subject.complete()`. Please let me know, what I am doing wrong, and thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a more thorough look at the RxJS in general. There are a lot of things to learn there..